# interpolation and appending outputs to list is taking forever in for loop

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, append, linear-interpolation

I am attaching a test excel file named 'df2.xlsx' here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U55lXyZSYguiQUH0AOB_v8yhKcbMGNQs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102781316443126205856&rtpof=true&sd=true that has 58673 lines and I have imported it as a dataframe and using the following attached code calculated 'D50' via **interp1d** linear interpolation. D50 is 50 percentile values, that's why I needed the interplotion.  The columns I have used to interpolate are con13c,con12c,con2c,con3c,......,con11c,con14c. Index of con13c and con14c are 17 and 29. I have stored the outputs into an empty list using append(). However, the performance of the code is slow.

The main excel file/text file will have 4928526 instead of the attached excel files 58673  lines and it took more than 20 minutes to finish the D50 calculation for the main excel file. Let me know if there is a way to make it faster by reading the df chunk by chunk and running into multiprocessor.In the main excel file there will be 100s of different TS value and for each TS value there will be 58673 lines. So in the test excel file 'df2.xlsx' all the data is for only one specific TS. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


dt=pd.read_excel('df2.xlsx', index_col=0) 

# check column index
dt.columns.get_loc("con14c")
x=[0.00001, 0.00004675, 0.000088,   0.000177,   0.000354,   0.000707,   0.001414,   0.002828,   
                   0.005657,    0.011314,   0.022627,   0.045254,   0.6096]
x=np.array(x)
xx=np.log(x)
dfs =[]
for i in range(0, len(dt)): # loop through the rows of dt
    y1=dt.iloc[i,17:30]

    y1=np.array(y1,dtype=np.float)
    f = interp1d( y1,xx, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.log(y1[0])) #fill_value='extrapolate'
    x_new=np.exp(f(.5))
    print(np.exp(x_new))
    dfs.append(x_new)
dt['D50']=dfs
```

Comment: To `interp1d` you provide arguments y and x swappped (x should be first, then y). Was that your intention?

Comment: yes,it was intentional.thanks.

Comment: That's sad, because I got improvement 500x, but requirement for this was providing many `y` at the same time to interp1d (`y` can have shape (NxD) while `x` can only have shape (N,))

Comment: In my problem, x is  same for all the iterations but y is changing every time. n every looop y is  taking some data from each row from the dataframe. Let me know if there is a way to implement your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a test on my PC and it reduced to 30% of the original run time by doing a simple change. Before it takes 9 seconds now it only takes about 2 seconds.

1. remove the print
2. Do not index the pd.DataFrame as it is extremely slow. Convert it to a numpy array first and index on that:

```
# outside the for loop
dt_arr = dt.values

# ... other codes

y1 = dt_arr[i,17:30]
```

Since you are only interested in 0.5:

```
dfs1 = []
dfs2 = []
for i in range(0, len(dt)): # loop through the rows of dt
    y1=dt_arr[i, 17:30]

    y1=np.array(y1,dtype=np.float)
    f = interp1d( y1,xx, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.log(y1[0])) #fill_value='extrapolate'
    x_new=np.exp(f(.5))
    dfs1.append(x_new)
    
    # I don't know if your data is sorted, if so you can ignore this part
    sort_idx = np.argsort(y1)
    xx_sorted = xx[sort_idx]
    y1_sorted = y1[sort_idx]
    # I think your fill value is a bit weird as you are using same values for both ends. You might want to check that
    if y1_sorted[-1] < 0.5 or y1_sorted[0] > 0.5:
        dfs2.append(y1[0])
    else:
        idx = np.argmax(y1_sorted > 0.5)
        x0 = xx_sorted[idx-1]
        x1 = xx_sorted[idx]
        z0 = y1_sorted[idx-1]
        z1 = y1_sorted[idx]
        dfs2.append(np.exp(x0 + (0.5-z0)*(x1-x0)/(z1-z0)))
```

Comment: With your modification now, it takes 24s while previously it was taking 32s. 
     dfs =[]                                                                                                                              
     dt_arr = dt.values  
     for i in range(0, len(dt)): 
           y1 = dt_arr[i,17:30]
           y1=np.array(y1,dtype=np.float)
           f = interp1d( y1,xx, kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.log(y1[0])) 
           x_new=np.exp(f(.5))
    
           dfs.append(x_new)
     dt['D50']=dfs

Comment: try not to post code in comment as it is hard to read. Are you only looking to evaluate your function at .5? If so there is no need to use interp1d and it will be way faster.

Comment: Didn't understand your question regarding 0.5. By 0.5 I wanted to find the  50 percentile values which will be 'D50', it's a grain size distribution problem of sediment analysis. which other function you would suggest using instead of interp1d?

Comment: I mean if you are only interested in evaluating the interpolated function `f` at 0.5? If so you do not need to interpolate the whole curve right? Since it is linear you only care about the points closest to 0.5.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. Then how do I find the two points in each row that is just below and above 0.5.  These two points may not be always in the same column. So, I will have to find the very first value that is greater or equal than 0.5 and the value just before it. Could you please tell me if you know how to do that for each rows using that loop? Thanks.

Comment: @ZVY545 see the updated answer. It is more than 50% faster on my PC and you can compare the results of `dfs1` and `dfs2`.

Comment: Z Li, running your whole code to get both dfs1 and dfs2 takes 24.73s and only dfs2 is taking 22.35s in my pc. Is it the interpolation or the append() that is taking longer time? Thanks for the other approach to get dfs2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239898/discussion-between-z-li-and-zvy545).

Comment: Z Li, I ran your code for the 1gb file and it finished in  2min 29s. Initially my code took more than 40 minutes for the 1gb file. So, basically your answer solved my problem. Thanks much. I will post another question tomorrow which I am facing problem. It's how to write the D50 values into a textfile from the dfs2 dataframe in the attached file format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C3dFMFWvEFeShcilJMb4bx-gRLynUHNw/view?usp=sharing